# Xamarin Android - Setting TextSize from Dimension file

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android project where I am using dimension files to specify text sizes, paddings, margins etc for different screen sizes/resolutions.

I have noticed that there is a pronounced difference between setting the value directly within the layout and within code.

For example, if I add the following to a TextView the layout XML

`android:textSize="@dimen/nav_tile_text_size"`

then I would expect the result to be the same as doing this in code

`myTextView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, _context.Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.nav_tile_text_size))`

The dimension file contains the following:

`<dimen name="nav_tile_text_size">17sp</dimen>`

but the resulting UI shows that the size has not been correctly applied

[image: Emulator Screenshot]

What am I missing here??

Comment: did you try with different unit? I think the problem is with sp.

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni - Although the documentation is unclear in some areas it is definite about using SP for text sizes so that it accounts for any font scaling applied by the user. It works fine when setting directly in the layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's correct. You would need to either use

```
myTextView.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Sp, Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.nav_title_text_size)/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
```

Unit, otherwise  gets multiplied by the density of the phone. I have personally checked this code, and it works.

Comment: You know, I thought this may be the case but reading the following from the Android Developer page I was confused: "Similarly, you should prefer the sp (scale-independent pixel) to define text sizes. The sp scale factor depends on a user setting and the system scales the size the same as it does for dp". I don't need to do any post-processing when reading in a DP value so didn't think I would need to for an SP value - maybe I've just not bumped into the issue with DP yet.

Comment: Well I've tested this on a number of devices (mdpi > xxhdpi) and it certainly does appear that this is the solution. I do find it odd though that setting the same property (TextSize) using the same value has to be done in a different way. There is probably a reason for it but it would be useful if this was in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: Well here's an anomaly - I've added another TextView and set the text size as above. When I run the app on a Sony Tablet S (10inch running 4.0.3 and classed as xlarge) all three lines of text are the same size! Furthermore, if I set 'Large Text' in Accessibility all lines increase in size but the first one (set in the layout) is now smaller than the other two (which are both the same, increased, height).